# Seleccionar imagen al hacer click en el botón derecho o botón izquierdo

Tags: javascript

Les pido, por favor, ayuda. En la parte inferior hay una tabla con un botón izquierdo y un botón derecho. Entre los botones hay 4 imágenes.

Necesito que cuando haga click en el botón derecho se seleccione (debe notarase la selección)la primera imágen empezando desde lado izquierdo, luego la segunda y así hasta regresar a la primera. Lo mismo debería suceder al hacer click en el botón izquierdo seleccionandose las imágenes desde el lado derecho.

```js
cambiarIzq(){
 
}


cambiarDer(){
   
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Anzuelos</title>
<link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>

<body>
<div id="marco">
 <header>
 
 <div id="divrs">
  <img class="imgrs" src="../imagenes/social/face.jpg" onMouseOver="ampliar(0)" onMouseOut="reducir(0)" >
  <img class="imgrs" src="../imagenes/social/twit.jpg" onMouseOver="ampliar(1)" onMouseOut="reducir(1)">
  <img class="imgrs" src="../imagenes/social/inst.jpg" onMouseOver="ampliar(2)" onMouseOut="reducir(2)">
 </div>
 
 <h1>Universidades del Perú</h1>
 <div id="divhora"></div>
 <img id="imgbaner" src="../imagenes/univ/universidades.jpg">     
 </header>
 
 <aside>
   <h3>Universidades</h3>
   <article class="artred" onMouseOver="mostrar(0)" onMouseOut="ocultar(0)" onClick="verimagen(0)">
    <img src="../imagenes/univ/callao.jpg">
    <div>es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao es Callao</div>
   </article>
   <article class="artred" onMouseOver="mostrar(1)" onMouseOut="ocultar(1)" onClick="verimagen(1)">
    <img src="../imagenes/univ/san marcos.jpg">
    <div>es San Marcos es San Marcos es San Marcos es San Marcos es San Marcos es San Marcos es San Marcos</div>
   </article>
   <article class="artred" onMouseOver="mostrar(2)" onMouseOut="ocultar(2)" onClick="verimagen(2)">
    <img src="../imagenes/univ/uni.jpg">
    <div>Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni Es la Uni</div>
   </article>
   <article class="artred" onMouseOver="mostrar(3)" onMouseOut="ocultar(3)" onClick="verimagen(3)">
    <img src="../imagenes/univ/villarreal.jpg">
    <div>es Villarreal es Villarreal es Villarreal es Villarreal es Villarreal es Villarreal es Villarreal</div>
   </article>
 </aside>
 
 <section>
  <h2 id="h2red">Universidades</h2>
  <img id="imgred" src="../imagenes/univ/san marcos.jpg"> 
  <table border=2>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="../imagenes/flechas/izquierda.png" width="50" height="50" align="top" onClick="cambiarIzq()">
        <td><img id="imgabajo0" src="../imagenes/univ/callao.jpg" width="200" height="200">
        <td><img id="imgabajo1" src="../imagenes/univ/san marcos.jpg" width="200" height="200">
        <td><img id="imgabajo2" src="../imagenes/univ/uni.jpg" width="200" height="200">
        <td><img id="imgabajo3" src="../imagenes/univ/villarreal.jpg" width="200" height="200">
        <td><img src="../imagenes/flechas/derecha.png" width="50" height="50" align="top" onClick="cambiarDer()">   
        </tr>
        </table>  
 </section>
  <footer>
     <table id="tablapie">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="../imagenes/univ/san marcos.jpg" />        
                </td>
                <td>

 EE
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </footer>
</div>

</body>
<script src="../js/codigos2.js"></script>
</html>
```